# Change color of similar word in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In PHPStorm, when you select a variable name in Javascript, it highlights all the other occurrences of that variable with a light background. How do you change the color of this background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in Settings (Win/Linux) or Preferences (Mac) then

> Editor/Colors & Fonts/General/Identifier under caret.

There you can set various options, like Foreground, Background, Error Stripe Mark and, probably what is of your interest the most, Effects.

Comment: thanks for your answer. by the way, what's Error Stripe Mark?

Comment: @user3576887 Marker on scrollbar -- so that you can see that place (with error/warning/search-result/etc) across whole file.